# Using a subfolder outside of Wordpress is giving 404 errors

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have Wordpress installed on root and I'm using a subfolder called "uploads" for a file uploading script I'm using. The problem is I get 404 errors when navigating to a subpage within Wordpress (site.com/subpage). I believe it's a problem with my htaccess file. I've tried several variations, but this is what I'm currently using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any clues on what is producing the 404 error would be much appreciated!

Comment: Ok be specific here. Are you getting a Wordpress 404 or a Apache 404? Those are different. Also is the subpage a wordpress subpage or just some other non wordpress subpage?

Comment: Apache 404. The subpages are Wordpress subpages. As a side note, it works when not using permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try replacing your rewrite base with the path to your subfolder?

i.e. from

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /subpage/
```

Do this in all the rewrite base statements in your htaccess

Comment: Thanks for the response, but wouldn't this brake the whole Wordpress site? I need the entire site to work, not just a single subpage. Sorry if I didn't explain this clear.